# python Tkinter: how to disallow a window growing bigger than screen size

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

My routine adds buttons to a window in tkinter. At some point the window becomes bigger (in height) than my actual screen and I cannot access the buttons at the bottom anymore.

Demo code:

```
from Tkinter import *

n_buttons = 20 # <- change this as you wish for testing the code

def generate_buttons(n):

    for i in range(n):
        button = Button(myframe, text="Button Clone", height=4)
        button.grid(row=i)

root = Tk()
myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack()

generate_buttons(n=n_buttons)

root.mainloop()
```

As a first attempt, I placed the following code into my loop:

```
if root.winfo_height() > root.winfo_screenheight():
    print("I'm full!")
    break
```

But 1) it does not work and 2) I'd strongly prefer a solution that checks if the window can take another button **before** it is created, so that I do not have to destroy it afterwards.

In my real code the buttons a placed as a 2D-grid and my first reaction to an overload of my window would be to increase the number of columns in my frame and then to reduce the height of all buttons. Again, it would be bad if I had to re-generate all buttons until all requirements are met. It would be great if you could help me with a solution that checks if the geometry is possible, before the first button is created. Thanks!

Comment: So, you want your loop to exit as soon as there's no more room for buttons?

Comment: @BryanOakley: That would be the "minimum goal". Better: have the code check if the expected number of buttons would exceed window size and react accordingly (e.g. decrease button size or print an error) before entering the loop.

Comment: scrollbar is not an option in your case ?

Comment: @PRMoureu: Not really. Maybe as a security option in case the other approach fails, so that at least the user reaches the settings that are on the bottom of my root widget. The program is a jingle palette. I cannot afford scrolling, because I have to find the button as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know if a widget will fit since there are so many variables. For example, padding, margins, other widgets on the screen, etc.

That being said, since you know your own application you can account for that. The only thing that's missing is knowing how tall a button is. You can get that from tkinter with the `winfo_reqheight` and `winfo_reqwidth` methods which return the height and width requested by the button. Then, it's just a matter of math.

Comment: `print( sum(map(lambda x: x.winfo_reqheight(),myframe.children.values())))`

Comment: `reqheight` is a cool method. I used `update()` on my widget to get its real height but that takes too long and lets the user see buttons pop up in real time (which is ugly). 

I was about to ask how I can compare the root size and the screen size. I did `root.winfo_height()`, but in fact I can use reqheight on that as well: 
if `root.winfo_reqheight > root.winfo_screenheight(): # ...`

Comment: @PRMoureu: I have buttons placed in columns as well. Your solution sums up the height of ALL my widgets in root, doesn't it?

Comment: @offeltoffel: you can solve the "... lets the user see buttons pop up" by temporarily moving the whole window off-screen with the `geometry` method (eg: `root.geometry("+10000+10000")`)

Comment: @offeltoffel nope, only `myframe` children in my example, but you could change it to makes sense with your layout (as it sum all widgets, you don't want to add the 2 columns indeed)